# Prolog prob with "list" dont know why

Tags: prolog

I have another problem now

```
communs(piece(C1, F1, T1, Co1),piece(C2, F2, T2, Co2)) :- 
    C1 = C2;
    F1 = F2;
    T1 = T2;
    Co1 = Co2.

line((A,_),(A_,_)) :-
    A_ = A.

row((_,A),(_,A_)) :-
    A_ = A.

win_line([]).
win_line([(_,_),_]).
win_line([(A,P)|[(A_,P_)|Reste]]):-
    line(A,A_),
    communs(P,P_),
    win_line(Reste).
```

and i actually want to do something but i don't now how : 
i want to get a list with only coordinate from the same line for example (1,1), (1,2), (1,3),

i tried this but i don't think it's correct :

```
selct_line([],[]).
select_line([(A,P)|[(A_,P_)|Reste]], _):-
    line(A,A_),
    select_line(Reste,[(A,P)|[(A_,P_)]).
```

Comment: `commun(P, Rest)` looks like the second argument for `commun` (namely, `Rest`) is expected to be a list. But the *only* predicate clause you show for `commun` has `p(C2, F2, T2, C2)` as an argument, which is not a list. So your call to `commun(P, Rest)` will always fail. As a side note, your clause could simply be written as `commun(p(C, F, T, Co), p(C, F, T, Co)).` I can't offer much advice beyond that since it's not clear to me what `commun` is intended to do. It looks like you might be messing a clause. What you show doesn't do much but unify the two arguments.

Comment: I am going to explain the problem : what i want to do is : commun take to piece and verify if they have an attribute in commun (C,F,T,C) and win_list to test if in a liste of pieces "p" we have only pieces that has an attribute in commun

Comment: Also as I mentioned `Rest` is itself a list because it is the tail of a list. `[Rest]` is a list of lists with just one element, `Rest`. So you just want `win_list(Rest)`.

Comment: i resolved the problem right now by testing this  win_list([]).
win_list([_]).
win_list([Piece|[B|Reste]]) :-
 pieces_communes(Piece,B),
    win_list([Reste]).

Comment: This is still buggy. I have a long answer prepared, but it's easier to post if I don't have to write "in the original question you wrote X, but in a comment you wrote Y". Can you please update the original question (click "edit") to show only the new code you have? Also, the code as posted has singleton variable warnings. Please fix those first!

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Please remove all code that is not needed, and please fix the naming of `communs` vs. `pieces_communes`. **You are making it hard to help you.** We want to help you. But you are giving us code that we cannot test without trying to fix stuff ourselves. Also, please don't just say "I have an error". Show us the actual error message.

Comment: Sorry for that, i think i ve removed all code not needed.

Comment: Thanks. Your syntax error is because you are missing a closing `)` at the end of your query!

Comment: Oh Oups, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have figured out almost all of the issues, well done! But there are few more things to note:

First, using `A` and `A_` as the names of different variables is valid, but *very* unusual and *very* hard to read. It's better to use `A1` and `A2`, for example.

Second, you are confusing yourself with the syntax. Consider:

```
?- List = [(A1,P1)|[(A2,P2)|Reste]].
List = [ (A1, P1), (A2, P2)|Reste].
```

It's clearer for both you and your readers to use the second, more usual syntax. Both describe the same term, but the second one makes it clearer that you have a list that starts with two pairs `(A1, P1)` and `(A2, P2)` followed by some list `Reste`.

Third, let's look at the solutions generated by Prolog for the definition you have:

```
?- win_line(Line), length(Line, Length).
Line = [],
Length = 0 ;
Line = [ (_G983, _G984), _G986],
Length = 2 ;
Line = [ ((_G992, _G993), piece(_G998, _G999, _G1000, _G1001)), ((_G992, _G996), piece(_G998, _G1004, _G1005, _G1006))],
Length = 2 ;
Line = [ ((_G992, _G993), piece(_G998, _G999, _G1000, _G1001)), ((_G992, _G996), piece(_G998, _G1004, _G1005, _G1006)), (_G1011, _G1012), _G1014],
Length = 4 ;
Line = [ ((_G992, _G993), piece(_G998, _G999, _G1000, _G1001)), ((_G992, _G996), piece(_G998, _G1004, _G1005, _G1006)), ((_G1020, _G1021), piece(_G1026, _G1027, _G1028, _G1029)), ((_G1020, _G1024), piece(_G1026, _G1032, _G1033, _G1034))],
Length = 4 ;
```

etc. All of the lists generated are of even length! Presumably you also want to accept lists of length 1, 3, 5, etc?

The second clause of `win_line/1` is particularly strange and underspecified:

```
win_line([(_,_),_]).
```

Even ignoring the pair of coordinates, this allows us to prove things like this:

```
?- win_line([_, hello_world]).
true .
```

Shouldn't this be a *pair* of a coordinate pair and a `piece` term? That is, you would probably want something more like this:

```
win_line([((_,_),_)]).
```

Which behaves like this:

```
?- win_line([(0,1), hello_world]).
false.

?- win_line([((0,1), hello_world)]).
true .
```

But even better:

```
win_line([((_,_), piece(_,_,_,_))]).
```

which gives:

```
?- win_line([((0,1), hello_world)]).
false.

?- win_line([((0,1), piece(a,b,c,d))]).
true .
```

With this the enumeration of results makes more sense:

```
?- win_line(Line), length(Line, Length).
Line = [],
Length = 0 ;
Line = [ ((_G986, _G987), piece(_G989, _G990, _G991, _G992))],
Length = 1 ;
Line = [ ((_G992, _G993), piece(_G998, _G999, _G1000, _G1001)), ((_G992, _G996), piece(_G998, _G1004, _G1005, _G1006))],
Length = 2 ;
Line = [ ((_G992, _G993), piece(_G998, _G999, _G1000, _G1001)), ((_G992, _G996), piece(_G998, _G1004, _G1005, _G1006)), ((_G1014, _G1015), piece(_G1017, _G1018, _G1019, _G1020))],
Length = 3 ;
Line = [ ((_G992, _G993), piece(_G998, _G999, _G1000, _G1001)), ((_G992, _G996), piece(_G998, _G1004, _G1005, _G1006)), ((_G1020, _G1021), piece(_G1026, _G1027, _G1028, _G1029)), ((_G1020, _G1024), piece(_G1026, _G1032, _G1033, _G1034))],
Length = 4 .
```

Fourth, this now behaves like this:

```
?- win_line([((0,0), piece(a,b,c,d)), ((0,1), piece(a,b,c,d)), ((1,1), piece(now, something, completely, different))]).
true .
```

You enforce a relationship between the first two elements of the list, but not between the second and the third. This is because for a list of this form you call `communs` on the first two elements, but *not* on the second and the third.

The usual way of checking every adjacent pair of elements in Prolog is by following this pattern:

```
valid_list([]).
valid_list([_]).
valid_list([A, B | Rest]) :-
    valid_pair(A, B),
    valid_list([B | Rest]).
```

That is, the element `B` is passed back into the recursive call. So if you call this on a list of the form `[A, B, C]`, this will call both `valid(A, B)` and `valid(B, C)`. Your code only checks the first of these but not the second, so it accepts invalid lists.

Finally, these terms of the form `((0,1), piece(...))` become hard to read with all the parentheses. It would be better to use a format like `move(0, 1, piece(...))`. That would make it a bit harder to get confused as you did with the second clause of `win_line`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i will fix all that but the exerciece is to tell if pieces has something in commun () an attribute in commun) in a board for example, if in the firste line we have (p(a,b,c,d),p(a,e,f,g),p(a,k,l,m), p(a,x,y,z)), so then it is a good line (win_line).

Comment: and the problem is that i have to write 3 predicates 1 for checking in a List if there is a winning line, second predicate to check if in List there is a winning row , and the third to check in diagonal. and in the liste we have the positions of all pieces in the board. I don't know if i'm going well

Comment: Good luck! If you have a new question, please submit a new question. It's hard to discuss stuff in these comments.

Comment: I can't ask another question :(